# CakePHP 3 : returns true even if data is not fetched from database

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.2

I'm working in CakePHP 3.2. There is a table `user_addresses` from which I'm trying to fetch all records of an user

```
public function myFun()
{
    $this->loadModel('UserAddresses');
    $user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    $userAddresses = $this->UserAddresses->find('all', [
       'conditions' => [
           'user_id' => $user_id
       ]
    ]);
    if (empty($userAddresses)) {
       echo 'Hello';               // for testing only
    } else {
       echo 'World';
    }
}
```

To check it, I added `myFun` to controller's `beforeFilter`

```
$this->Auth->allow(['myFun']);
```

and this prints **World** instead of **Hello** since there is no data retrieved from database because if user is not logged in then `$user_id` must be empty.

Comment: You should get a little more comfortable with debugging. So you have a problem with a value that doesn't seem to be what you expect it to be, well, the first thing that you should do, is to debug the value in order to figure what _exactly_ it actually is (`debug($userAddresses)`)! It may be obvious for people that know their cake where the problem is, but still such details should be in your question, often the problem even solves itself when gathering such information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check if `$user_id` is available then and then call `find()` method.

```
public function myFun()
{
    $this->loadModel('UserAddresses');
    $user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    if(empty($user_id)){
        echo "Not able to access this method";
        die();
    }
    $userAddresses = $this->UserAddresses->find('all', [
       'conditions' => [
           'user_id' => $user_id
       ]
    ]);
    if (empty($userAddresses)) {
       echo 'Hello';               // for testing only
    } else {
       echo 'World';
    }
}
```